# Deadlock Example

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class DeadLockExampleTwo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final DeadLockExampleTwo d = new DeadLockExampleTwo();
    final DeadLockExampleTwo d1 = new DeadLockExampleTwo();

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            d.doSomething(d1);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            d1.doSomething(d);
        }
    }).start();
}

    public synchronized void doSomething(DeadLockExampleTwo e) {
        System.out.println("Doing "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        e.done(this);
    }
    public synchronized void done(DeadLockExampleTwo d) {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

The above code has the potential to cause a deadlock. d from first thread locks on the doSomething method, d1 from other thread acquires lock on the same method. What exactly happens when both objects have locked on the method? How are they blocking each other from executing the "done" method?

Comment: FWIW, any time you acquire locks on two objects simultaneously, as your example does, you're at extreme risk of deadlock. Unfortunately, as deadlock is often a race condition, it can be very hard to detect, and debugging mutexes has always been more of an ar form than a science to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deadlock *might* happen because the first thread is calling the following:

```
d.doSomething(d1);  // this is a synchronized method so locks on d
d1.done(...);       // this is a synchronized method so it tries to lock d1
```

While the other thread *might* at the same time call:

```
d1.doSomething(d);  // this locks d1
d.done(...);        // this tries to lock d
```

I use the word "might" above because there is a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).  If it occurs then the two threads each have one lock and are trying to get a lock on the other object.

As I mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223504/how-to-create-deadlock-using-these-two-threads-and-objects-of-classes-a-and-b), if you just run this once then it most likely will not deadlock since a thread will most likely finish before the other starts.  You will have to setup a loop and call it a number of times to get it to lock.

When you have `synchronized` on a method, it locks the *instance* of the object in question.  In this case it is locking either `d` or `d1`.

Comment: thanks gray , you are a "pro" :-)

Comment: Good explanation; I almost missed the part where done() was synchronized.